# LINQ Filter Nth Level Nested list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following hierarchy in my project :

1. Activity
2. Task
3. Step
4. Responses

This means an activity has many tasks, which in turn has many steps , a step has many responses.

Here are my POCO classes:

```
public class Activity
{
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public virtual ICollection<Step> Steps{ get; set; }
}


public class Step
{
    public virtual int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses{ get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual int ResponseText{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, I need to return a `List<Activity>` which is sorted by `ActivityId` and  has Steps ordered by `DisplayOrder` and also a Responses which only belong to a given `UserId`.

Here's what I have tried:

```
Activities.ToList()
                .ForEach((activity) => activity.Tasks.ToList()
                .ForEach((task) => task.Steps = task.Steps.OrderBy(s => s.DisplayOrder).ToList()
                .ForEach((step) =>  step.Responses = step.Responses.Where(r => r.UserId == RequestorUserId)))
                ));
```

Which is giving me an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to `ICollection<Step>`

Comment: I've provided an answer, if it helps you please upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ForEach extension method doesn't return anything and you are trying to set the result to task.Steps.  You can achieve the desired result by using the Select method to alter the objects in line

```
    Activities.ToList()
            .ForEach((activity) => activity.Tasks.ToList()
            .ForEach((task) => task.Steps = task.Steps.OrderBy(s => s.DisplayOrder).ToList()
            .Select((step) =>  
                {
                    step.Responses = step.Responses.Where(r => r.UserId == 1).ToList();
                    return step;
                }).ToList()));
```

Also It might be worth changing your types if possible to IEnumerable rather than ICollection as you then won't need all of the ToList() calls.

If you need to assign the result then you'll need to replace the first ForEach as well - try something like:

```
var a = Activities.ToList()
            .Select((activity) =>
                {
                    activity.Tasks.ToList()
                        .ForEach((task) => task.Steps = task.Steps.OrderBy(s => s.DisplayOrder).ToList()
                        .Select((step) =>
                            {
                                step.Responses = step.Responses.Where(r => r.UserId == 1).ToList();
                                return step;
                            }).ToList());
                    return activity;
                });
```

Comment: when I assign it to some `var` variable, is says cannot assign void to an implicitly types variable

Comment: @SJMan, that's going to be exactly the same issue - i.e. that ForEach doesn't return anything.  If you need to assign it - which wasn't explicit in your question - you will need to convert the first ForEach into a select as well - see my edited answer

Comment: @SJMan Did that solve the issue?  If so, please accept the solution as it encourages people to actually help answer your questions.